# ASP.NET MVC client connect ids4 SSo [Authorize] 302 redirect always

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4, openid-connect

Client code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
               .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
               {
                   options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authorization/AccessDenied";
               })
               .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
               {
                   options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                   options.Authority = "https://jpprojectsso.inthink.top:5000"; //
                   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                   options.ClientId = "TestClient";
                   options.ClientSecret = "Client Secrets";
                   options.SaveTokens = true;
                   options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                   options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                   options.Scope.Clear();
                   options.Scope.Add(OidcConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
                   options.Scope.Add(OidcConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);

               });
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    var user = User.Identity.Name;
    return View();
}
```

ids4 connection client success. But the client always 302 redirect to sso and sso successfully redirects to client... in loop.

My sso use Jp project ids4. How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug...
in void Configure function.

app.UseAuthorization() should be executed after app.UseAuthentication()

Then it works.